# C++ MS Visual Studio Exp 2013 IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I created two separate projects in MS Visual Studio, W59Components.cpp(console) and Frequency.cpp(DLL). I created a class ReadFile in W59Components>ReadFile.h and am trying to use that class in a different MS project Frequency.cpp. I did look at other forums on the topic with no luck.

For some reason I am getting an IntelliSense error, "IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier."

Compiler Errors:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 't'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> error C2365: 'ReadFile' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
>
> see declaration of 'ReadFile'

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "../../scripts/DLLs/Wave59_SDK.h"
using namespace std;

#include "ReadFile.h"
ReadFile t;     // Should Reconize "ReadFile" as a class

//#include "../../scripts/DLLs/demo/Demo.h" 

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern "C" double __declspec(dllexport) average(WAVE59_DATASTRUCT *price_ptr,
    int currentptr, int *int_args, int num_int_args, double *double_args,
    int num_double_args, char **string_args, int num_string_args);
```

How do you #include a header file from a different MS Visual Studio project?

Here is the header file, I didn't want to burden you with the function definition:

```
/* ReadFile.h
* Reads a incomming file and splits it into a multidemensional array */

# include <istream>
# include <fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class ReadFile {
public:
    ReadFile(){};
    ~ReadFile(){};

    void ReadTheFile(string path = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Wave59\\TestWriteFile.txt");
    void split(string delimiter, string text, string pArray[]);
    int getColumnNum(){ return this->columnNum; }
    int WriteFile(string message[], int lenMessage, string path = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Wave59\\W59Components-WrittenFile.txt");

    double f2Array[20][1000];

private:
    void readFile(double pArray[], string path = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Wave59\\TestWriteFile.txt");
    void sortArray(double returnArray[], int modNum);

    // Initalize VARS
    const int SIZE = 10000;
    double fArray[10000];       // file data
    int columnNum;                      // Number of colums in the file data, which is different arrays of data
};
```

Comment: ***How do you #include a header file from a different MS Visual Studio project?*** I normally add the path to the Additional Include Directories. However the way you included it should be fine. And it was fine since you would have had a different error if Visual Studio could not find the header. Perhaps you have a problem with your #ifdef guards in ReadFile.h.

Comment: You need to show the contents of `ReadFile.h`.

Comment: The exact compiler error would also help. Intellisense errors are not always compiler errors.

Comment: @n.m. how do you show the contents of the header file?

Comment: Paste the text of the header file in your original question.

Comment: @drescherjm Maybe the 'extern "C"...' is causing the problem. I tried to copy the ReadFile.h into the Frequency directory, but it's still giving me those errors. Would turning the ReadFile.h into a source file fix the problem, I don't know?

Comment: I think your problem is windows defines ReadFile. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx by including <windows.h> you are getting a conflict between your class and the winapi ReadFile.

Comment: @drescherjm that was it, Thank you. I was trying to figure out how to credit you with the answer, but it said just comment so I did. I'm very thankful that you found that.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the winapi defines ReadFile. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

By including `windows.h` you are getting a conflict between your class and the winapi ReadFile.